# How to use *args in python

Tags: python, oop, args, keyword-argument

I have a functions module that has some functions all with some common inputs, and others that are particular to them. e.g.

```
def func_a(time_series, window ='1D'):

def func_b(time_series, window ='1D', availability_history ): 

def func_c(time_series, window ='1D', max_lag=25, use_probability ='T'):
```

I am trying to run these functions in a loop as follows:

```
func_list = [func_a, func_b, func_c]
windows = ['1D', '5D']
params = ['', hist, (25, 'T')]

for i_func, func in enumerate(func_list):
    class_obj = class_X(A,B,func)

    for window in windows:
        args = (window, params[i_func]) # params is a list or tuple of other params for funcs e.g. 
        class_obj.run_func(args)
```

And in another module

```
class class_X(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, func_to_run):
        self.a = a
        self.ts = b
        self.method = func_to_run

    def generate_output(self, *args):
        return self.method(self.ts, args) # time series is common and fixed for all, other params differ or change
```

The above code wouldn't work because I think the functions that I am calling need to be changed to make use of `*args`rather than having fixed defined params.

I think `*args` is meant for functions where number of input params are not known, but I am trying to use it in a case where the number of input params is known, but varies across different functions in a loop.

Is there any fix for this where I don't have to modify the functions module and can still pass all the required params as a single object (`e.g. list or tuple`)?

EDIT-

macromoonshine's answer states I can use kwargs like this:

```
def generate_output(self, **kwargs):
    return self.method(self.ts, kwargs)
```

With this modification you can call generate_outputs() as follows:

```
x.generate_outputs( window ='1D', max_lag=25, use_probability ='T')
```

where xis an instance of your class X

Can this be enhanced so I can pass args other than time_series and window as a lookup value in a loop e.g.

```
x.generate_outputs( window ='1D', params[iloop])
```

where

```
params[iloop] = max_lag=25, use_probability ='T'
```

I tried doing this:

```
params = (30, "F")
x.generate_outputs( window, *params)
```

but get an error

```
TypeError: generate_output() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Comment: look up keyword arguments. `**kwargs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `**kwargs` instead which allows arbitrary keyword parameters. This should be easier than chinging each function. You have just to modify your `generate_outputs()` method in your code:

```
def generate_output(self, **kwargs):
    return self.method(self.ts, kwargs)
```

With this modification you can call `generate_outputs()` as follows:

```
x.generate_outputs(time_series, window ='1D', max_lag=25, use_probability ='T')
```

where `x`is an instance of your class `X`.

If you want to pass the `kwargs` from a `dict` instead named parameter, you have to prefix the dictionary variable with `**`. The adapted code should look like this:

```
params = [{max_lag: 35, use_probability: 'F'}, ... ]
TS= [1,2,3,4]

for i_func, func in enumerate(func_list):
    class_obj = class_X(TS, func)
    for window in windows:
        req_args = dict(params[i_func])
        req_args['window'] = 0
        class_obj.generate_output(**req_args)
```

Comment: Thanks,  how can i pass the arguments other than time_series and window as something I lookup via a list/tuple etc. e.g. `x.generate_outputs(time_series, window ='1D', params [i])` where  `params[i] = max_lag=25, use_probability ='T'`

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've adapted my post for this.