# How to use *args in a Python function

Tags: python, function

There are quite a few questions about positional/*args arguments such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236272/how-to-use-args-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163846/positional-argument-follows-keyword-argument), but I cannot use their answers to solve my issue, thus the following question.

I defined a function where it can take an unknown number of additional arguments like this

```
def my_func(a, b, display=False, *args):
    obj = <build something from a>
    obj.add(b)
    for arg in args:
        obj.add(arg)
    if display:
        print(obj)

    return obj
```

But when I ran it with an additional argument

```
my_func(a, b, display=True, c)
```

I got this error

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

As I have little almost to nothing in programming, I cannot understand what the error means. Could you please help me out how to fix it?

Comment: Put *args before display=False.

Comment: @Sohaib The issue is in the *calling*, not in the function `def`inition.

Comment: @Nemo In a nutshell, keyword arguments must follow positional arguments when calling: `my_func(a, b, c, display=True)`.

Comment: Thanks Sohaib and @deceze for your resuce. As I have no programming knowledge, I just blindly copied other people's codes here and there without understanding the fundamentals behind, thus making such mistakes that seem trivial to knowledgeable people. Maybe that's why I couldn't understand why the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163846/positional-argument-follows-keyword-argument can be applied in my case. Moreover, I think that question was too specific, not as general as mine?

Comment: @deceze, I forgot to mention that before posting the question, I did try `my_func(a, b, c, display=True)`  but got this error `TypeError: my_func() got multiple values for argument 'display'` which caused me at my wit's end!